# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

as you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/design-for-it-security).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/security/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/securitymeta/img/favicon.ico

We have also styled the site's [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/stacksecurity) account and the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) theme to reflect the new design. I will be working on the design conversion for the [blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/) very soon.

If you see any CSS bugs, please start a **new post** and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch!

Comment: It seems like the "user bar" left to the top search box have gone missing. I only have IE7 avaiable at the moment, so I cannot see if its the same for other browsers as well.

Comment: @Jin, thanks very much for the awesome design!

Comment: @Jin - The favicon trick isn't working for me at home for some reason.  Win7x64, FF 5.

Comment: @Iszi I can see it in FF5 fine both on Win and OSX. Have you tried clearing cache? Or visit the site in Incognito Mode?

Comment: @Jin - Private Browsing didn't work, but clearing cache did.  Thanks.