# We still don't have a 404 image

Tags: discussion, design

Back when we were discussing site design, [@Jin came up with this design question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/345/485) and we do have some answers which could be relevant to our [404 page](https://security.stackexchange.com/404).

I think we need to get something defined, as ours are very bland.

Bicycles have this for their [404](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/404):

[image]

Which I think is wonderful.

We are using an SEI standard [Captcha page (HAL)](https://security.stackexchange.com/captcha) and we have the [laptop/token Error page](https://security.stackexchange.com/error) but we need a 404.

Comment: Once a winning entry has been chosen, I'll update it!

Comment: Nothing to see here, move along

Comment: A play on security by obscurity?

Comment: @Jin uhuh. still no updates.

Answer (score 8):

Laptop workstation, no dock, with cables, with security cable, with no laptop.

Maybe I should just take a photo?

Or maybe a server missing from a rack would be even more obvious. Ooh, and empty equipment rack with all the cabling in place. Score.

That one will take some work. Anybody have access to a datacenter with some scheduled maintenance?

Comment: If you provide the photo, we can put it on the page for you. Just make sure it conveys "not found." All of your examples seem to, but some of the ones below -- while funny -- do not.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Bike inadequately locked up]

@WesleyDavid [posted this in the ServerFault chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7648928#7648928) and I thought it might fit well here.

[People](http://i26.photobucket.com/albums/c133/SharonTampons/f3b3269f.jpg) [are](http://playhappy.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/fail-owned-bike-lock-owner-fail.jpg) [not](http://cdn.motinetwork.net/motifake.com/image/demotivational-poster/0811/morons-demotivational-poster-1227797834.jpg) [very](http://failblog.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/fail-owned-bike-security-fail.jpg) [good](http://www.digdang.com/media/images/bike_lock_security_fail_4082.jpg) [at locking](http://www.imglols.com/wp-content/main/2012_03/bike-security-fail.jpg) [up](http://cdn.motinetwork.net/demotivationalposters.net/image/demotivational-poster/0912/security-bike-lock-demotivational-poster-1260545300.jpg) [bikes](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_MnFLs4aHEGE/TBPrMx67kdI/AAAAAAAAANU/YIt3Bfbj0Aw/s400/security-fail-bike-chained-poster.jpg).

These have potential too, maybe for the **429 Too Many Requests** response or **413 Request Entity Too Large**:

[image: http://www.techzoom.net/img/risk-bike.png]
[image: http://www.tensionnot.com/pictures/images/Bicycle/Bicycle-Security-Locks.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

How about specialized "honeypot" 404's for web.config, :$Data, or app.mdb (etc)

Answer (score 1):

**You're entering from an unexpected location**

[image]

Source: http://failblog.org/2009/05/22/security-fail-5/

Comment: Nah, this is an access violation - not an availability issue.  (Though, with the proper tools, it could become one.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not a dead thread yet!

**Let's give it a try anyways:**

### ERROR 404

Page Not Found

We couldn't find the page you requested. 
But since you are here, how about making this resolution?

[image]

To know more about strong passwords and other topics, you may-

Try searching for similar questions
Browse recent questions
Browse popular tags
If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.

---

*Ack*: Image taken from http://www.theemailadmin.com/2012/09/length-versus-complexity-the-great-password-debate-rages-on/. Cannot be reused directly. I suggest editing out the sentence at the bottom with something more relevant to SEC.SE

Comment: “Strong passwords (…) include uppercase, lowercase, numbers & special characters.” [NO!](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase).

Comment: @Gilles Hence I wrote that the last line better be re-phrased. I know it would cause a controversy otherwise :)

Comment: @Gilles A -1 for that last one line (which I anywas pointed out that it should be edited)?!? c'mon... at least give some credit for a possible concept for our 404 page!

Answer (score 0):

[image]