# Need new 404 image

Tags: discussion

It has been discussed [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/750/we-still-dont-have-a-404-image) for a competition for a new 404 image. It has aged away and no winner has been chosen. The initial 404 image was removed due to a copyright strike.