# InfoSec Ex Badges

Tags: discussion

One thing I've wondered since I've started contributing here is - how come the badges (That being the bronze, silver & gold) don't feature the lion as per the official logo?

I realise there could be issues due to the size of the badges but they don't even feature an outline, seems quite odd to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The badges (as well as the favicon and etc) are in the shape of the shield, upon which the Lion appears.

I'm sure if you dig through the ancient meta posts you can find one where Jin (the site designer) explains his logic behind the design language.

Comment: probably this one https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/design-for-it-security